# Should I disclose an interim temporary job that I took up between acceptance and joining new employment?

Tags: new-job, united-kingdom

I am based out of the UK.

I received a conditional offer from a large public sector organisation for a permanent role in the beginning of July, which I accepted. The instructions on the letter state that I am not to resign my role until an unconditional offer was made.

While the background checks were being done, I took up a week-long contract role with another organisation.

An unconditional offer was received from the public-sector job, last week and I'm due to join them in a week's time.

Do I need to disclose this week-long job, provide additional references, etc to my new employer? Will the payment from the week-long job, show on my P45 and raise questions?

Comment: Did you get another P45 from that week-long contract work?

Comment: I'm pretty sure "_The instructions_" not to resign were more "_strong advice_" ... i.e. to not burn your bridges unless or until you got an unconditional offer. It's not clear if you were in employment, then resigned and took a week's contract, or were not working at the time of those "instructions" and just filled-in some time with a contract. Even if it _was_ the first, I can't see your new employers caring that you "broke their instructions / advice" (especially if you now have an _unconditional_ offer).

Answer (score 3):

You were not employed by the organisation at the time, so there was no obligation to disclose it. That said, if you choose to use the P45 from the contract work, they're going to know.

My approach would be to let them know that you have some freelance/contract arrangements on the side when you start, but that you are happy to end these if required. Also, ask for a *new starter form* from your new employer so the P45 is not needed.

Comment: @Bilkokuya That's not what emergency tax is, that's Basic Rate and is applicable if box C is ticked. Box A is default tax code (1185L) and Box B is default on W1/M1 basis (aka Emergency Tax). If an HR or payroll department messes this up, you'll likely encounter many more payroll horror stories during your time there.